# Access media library from IOS WebView

Tags: ios, webview, uiwebview

I am loading a html which contains

```
<input type='file'>
```

So whenever I click that html input to access files, I am not able to access IOS media library. I tried the following:

```
NSString *javaScript = @"document.getElementByID('m-addtrack')";
NSString *response = [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:javaScript];
```

It didn't work. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIWebView_Class/#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006950-CH3-SW20  here u can find whatever you are looking for

Comment: tried with that , i am looking for another ways if anything there

Comment: Make sure the document is loaded completely

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Your Html View Template u need to a simple JS Stuff

Eg : A button with hyperlink

```
<a href="app://file"><button>Add File</button></a>
```

You can now get the click event of the "Add File" in IOS UIWebView request handler delegate method as below

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView )webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest )request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {
NSString *str=[request.URL absoluteString];
if ([str isEqualToString:@"app://file"]) {
        // get the file data or url here 
        NSString *javaScript = @"jsFunction(param as url or data)";
        NSString *response   = [webViewstringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:javaScript];
      }
}
```

Then in your webscript

```
<script>
   function jsFunction(data) {
       //Handle
   }
</script>
```